# Error while connecting a call using webRTC in React App: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, mern, peer

Whenever I am clicking on Call button, apparently call is accepted, I am getting my video but then I am getting this error

> Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: stable

It shows the error in this function:

```
async setLocalDescription(ans) {
    if (this.peer) {
      await this.peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(ans));
    }
  }
```

in peer.js

I looked up the internet, I am setting my LocalDescription before Remote Description, so that is fine.

MDN docs says

> This may mean that the RTCPeerConnection object is new, in which case both the localDescription and remoteDescription are null; it may also mean that negotiation is complete and a connection has been established.

How do I resolve it?

This is my code in React

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSocket } from "../context/SocketProvider";
import ReactPlayer from "react-player";
import peer from "../service/peer";

export default function Room() {
  const socket = useSocket();
  const [remoteSocketId, setRemoteSocketId] = useState(null);
  const [myStream, setMyStream] = useState();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState(null);

  const joinUser = useCallback((data) => {
    const { email, id } = data;
    setRemoteSocketId(id);
    console.log(`Email ${email} joined the room`, remoteSocketId);
  }, []);

  const handleCallUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: true,
    });
    const offer = await peer.getOffer();
    //console.log("Offer is", offer);
    socket.emit("user:call", { to: remoteSocketId, offer: offer });
    setMyStream(stream);
    //stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peer.addTrack(track, stream));
  }, [remoteSocketId, socket]);

  const handleIncomingCall = useCallback(
    async ({ from, offer }) => {
      setRemoteSocketId(from);
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      });
      setMyStream(stream);
      console.log(`Incoming Call`, from, offer);
      //await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
      const ans = await peer.getAnswer(offer);
      socket.emit("call:accepted", { to: from, ans });
    },
    [socket]
  );

  

  const handleCallAccepted = useCallback(
    ({ from, ans }) => {
      peer.setLocalDescription(ans);
      console.log("Call Accepted!");
    },
    [    ]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("user_joined", joinUser);
    socket.on("incoming:call", handleIncomingCall);
    socket.on("call:accepted", handleCallAccepted);
    return () => {
      socket.off("user_joined");
      socket.off("incoming:call", handleIncomingCall);
      socket.off("call:accepted", handleCallAccepted);
    };
  }, [
    socket,
    joinUser,
    handleIncomingCall,
    handleCallAccepted,
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> This is the Room</h1>
      <h2>{remoteSocketId ? "Connected" : "Not"}</h2>
      {/* {myStream && <button onClick={sendStreams}>Send Stream</button>} */}
      {remoteSocketId && <button onClick={handleCallUser}>CALL</button>}
      {myStream && (
        <>
          <h1>My Stream</h1>

          <ReactPlayer
            playing
            muted
            height="100px"
            width="200px"
            url={myStream}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my peer.js which is using all the WebRTC APIs

```
class PeerService {
  constructor() {
    if (!this.peer) {
      this.peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: [
              "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
              "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478",
            ],
          },
        ],
      });
    }
  }

  async getAnswer(offer) {
    if (this.peer) {
      await this.peer.setRemoteDescription(offer);
      const ans = await this.peer.createAnswer();
      await this.peer.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(ans));
      return ans;
    }
  }

  async setLocalDescription(ans) {
    if (this.peer) {
      await this.peer.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(ans));
    }
  }

  async getOffer() {
    if (this.peer) {
      const offer = await this.peer.createOffer();
      await this.peer.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));
      //console.log("Offer 2 is", offer);
      return offer;
    }
  }
}

export default new PeerService();
```

This is what my webRTC internals says

```
http://localhost:3000/, { iceServers: [stun:stun.l.google.com:19302, stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478], iceTransportPolicy: all, bundlePolicy: balanced, rtcpMuxPolicy: require, iceCandidatePoolSize: 0 }

ICE connection state: new
Connection state: new
Signaling state: new
ICE Candidate pair: (not connected)
ICE candidate grid
Stats Tables
Filter statistics by type including 
separate multiple values by `,`
media-playout (kind=audio, id=AP)
peer-connection (id=P)
Filter statistics graphs by type including 
separate multiple values by `,`
Stats graphs for media-playout (kind=audio, id=AP)
Stats graphs for peer-connection (id=P)
```